# Which way of indexing is most proper in this case?

Tags: c++, pointers

Can you tell me which function will work faster? Or perhaps they are both wrong and you know better way to do this. Thanks in advance.

```
double* solveDiagonal(double* A, double* B, int n)
{
    double* X = new double[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        X[i] = B[i] / A[i*n + i];

    return X;
}


double* solveDiagonal(double* A, double* B, int n)
{
    double* X = new double[n];
    double** pA = new double*[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        pA[i] = &A[i*n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        X[i] = B[i] / pA[i][i];

    delete [] pA;

    return X;
}
```

Comment: Profile it. (though I'd be surprised if the latter is faster)

Comment: The compiler will likely figure the address calculations out, making the first one better because it is simpler.

Comment: Consider returning a `std::vector<double>` instead of messing with `new[]` and `delete[]`.

Comment: Are you facing issues with the speed of either implementations? Premature optimisation is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I would guess the second one is slower due to more indirection and allocation, you really need to test and profile to answer this kind of question.